# Android Studio gives error "Could not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.0): No cached version available for offline mode"

Tags: android, android-studio

I have Android Studio v3.2. 
Every time I try to build with internet connected, the build process goes on forever.
When I try offline it gives me this error:

> Could not download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.0): No cached version available for offline mode

So I tries disabling offline mode in Settings > Gradle. Then I get this error:

> Unknown host 'dl.google.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
>   Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
>   Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle

So I downloaded Gradle and set Service directory path of Settings>Gradle to manually downloaded directory. Then I get this error:

> Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
>   Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle

Is there any way I can work offline or I can fix the online problem.

Comment: Try Invalidate Caches/Restart option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to have internet connectivity to download the maven library dependencies and gradle.

Comment: Is that one time or will happen everytime?

Comment: it download the dependencies first time.

Comment: I have internet connectivity but still getting the same issue, also tried adding the proxy. 
I can download .jar file when pasting the link on the browser but on android studio getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

go to FIle==>Setting==>Appearance==>System Settings==>HTTP Proxy
Set Auto Proxy click Apply and check the connection.
then File==>Sync with gradle files.

If it displays an edit proxy dialog ignore it and set "do not display thi dialog again"

Comment: It still giving the same error for me